# Dice probability of a number coming up a given number of times

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A fair $6$-sided die is tossed $7$. What is the probability that one number shows up three times, two numbers show up twice each, and the remaining do not show up at all?

---

I thought the first roll won't matter. The second roll has probability $1/6$ of matching the first, and the third has a probability $1/6$ of matching the first and second.

Then the fourth has probability $5/6$ of not matching the first three, the fifth has a probability $1/6$ of matching the fourth. Likewise, the sixth has probability $5/6$ and the last has probability $1/6$.

This gives me $\frac{1}{6^6} \cdot 20$, which is wrong.

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of 1-1-1-2-2-3-3 is $6^{-7}$.

The number of permutations of 1-1-1-2-2-3-3 is the multinomial coefficient $${7\choose3,2,2}={7!\over3!2!2!}=210$$

The number of ways to pick the three numbers that show up is $$6\times{5\choose2}=60$$

So the answer is the product of these three numbers.

Answer (score 0):

One error in your reasoning is that if you have already rolled $3,3,3,2,2$ with the first five rolls, you only required the sixth roll to be something different from $2$ (with probability $\frac56$), but actually it also must not be $3.$
So with $3,3,3,2,2$ for the first five rolls, the probability that the sixth roll will be "good" is only $\frac46$.
This tends to cause you to overcount the "good" sequences of rolls.

But the bigger error is that you have assumed that it is the first three rolls that are the three equal ones, the next two rolls are a pair, and the last two rolls are a pair.
That is, $3,3,3,2,2,5,5$ is a sequence of rolls that you count, but $2,3,3,2,5,5,3$ is not.
This causes a massive undercounting of rolls that completely overwhelms the other effect, so you end up with a much smaller result than the correct probability.